# How can I see progress in BackupLoupe?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, restore

I'm relieved to discover that BackupLoupe exists, probably for the same reason everyone else is: Time Machine Restores correct system errors but wipe all recent data from your hard drive. BackupLoupe allows you to put it back.

Unfortunately BackupLoupe does not automatically merge the contents of a folder that you want to restore - you have to either delete the existing folder you're restoring or restore millions of files individually. Obviously, merge is what everyone wants (but we don't get it). This should be a function of Time Machine (but that is a product from the software makers at Apple.)

BackupLoupe is a buggy program, and I find that after a comparison, I need to restart the program and scan a backup just to see any changes. Also, things simply disappear from the screen. Nevertheless, it is probably our ONLY option to combat the ruthless simplicity of Time Machine.

But I at least want to know if a process has begun in BackupLoupe, and see a percentage, timer and list of what is happening, preferably a check mark next to each restored file, subfolder and folder in real time. IS there a setting that allows me to monitor what is happening? Are there are settings that make this vital tool work intuitively that I should know about?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like to use BackupLoupe to locate the files I want to restore and not actually do the lifting.

Once you have a Finder window - you could use Finder to show you the progress of the copy or even use a tool custom designed for syncing folders that can be paused / stopped / resumed.

- http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com does file merges primarily but it's also nice for syncing folders
- https://www.panic.com/transmit/ is another wizard level program for managing files and copying them - it's also not exclusively for local copies but does that well.
- I like to use BackupLoupe to locate the files I want to restore and not actually do the lifting.

So in a nutshell, get a file moving tool and let BackupLoupe do the indexing / searching is my advice.